# C# Web API Request/Response Logging with OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I am having a tough time figuring this out, but when I use a custom message handler in my Web API (created in VS2013) none of the /token request get processed through my handler.

What I'm trying to do is assist our support crew by implementing some logging to save request / response values for a few days. This will allow them to see the request and responses as raw as possible.

It's working, for everything except "/token" requests. We need to process the requests and responses for "/token" and "/authenticate" as a large percentage of our support calls end up being username and password issues.

I also need to do this in a message handler so I can isolate the code to message handlers.

Here is a sample handler I'm testing with in an isolated project. It's only in place ATM to debug/test this issue. I've also implemented a DelegatingHandler as well with the same results.

```
public class MyMessageProcessingHandler : MessageProcessingHandler {
    protected override HttpRequestMessage ProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", request.Method, request.RequestUri));

        return request;
    }

    protected override HttpResponseMessage ProcessResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        Trace.WriteLine("response!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

in WebApiConfig.Register method I add the message handler to the config's message handler collection.
(I also tried Global.asax.cs is the Application_Start method)

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyMessageProcessingHandler());
```

The order doesn't seem to matter - I've tried it as the first line of code, or the last.I've tried to Insert after the passive message handler is added by

```
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new MyMessageProcessingHandler());
```

Whenever I make an api/Values request or any api/Controller request the custom message handler handles the request just fine. However, when I post (or get) to /token (yes-properly) the custom message handler doesn't process the request.

I would like to know how to use a Message Handler to process the /token & /authenticate requests. I appreciate all your help!

Thanks,

-Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with a custom IHttpModule. It ended doing what I wanted in the way I wanted it by giving me direct access to the requests and allowing me to inspect them; even the authentication requests.

Thanks to all that looked at my issue.